# How to iterate over variadic template pack during (pseudo?) runtime?

Tags: c++, input, variadic-templates

I want to create somewhat sibling of `std::fscanf()` (I know it's a C function). So, my interface is something like this:

```
template <charT, char_traits, ...>
std::size_t ts_scanf(is, format, opening_bracket, closing_bracket, args)
```

I decided to implement a C# version of reading from console, since it requires programmer to maintain only one sequence (the args part), not the arguments and format.

Here is how **C# version** works:

```
"text blah blah blah {0} {1} {0}", arg1, arg2
```

So, it infers types of arg1, arg2, and then reads the text in location where {N} stands into the appropriate argument.

**Algorithm** of what I want to do:

1.Find opening bracket

2.Try to parse an int, say N

3.if succeeded, get the Nth parameter from the pack, read into it using `is>>get<N>args`.

4.if failed,perform dumb read

5.Repeat 1 to 4 until the end of the format or until stream exhausts

So, when writing a loop I encountered **a problem**:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i = format.find(i, opening_bracket))
```

I found that I need to somehow expand the parameter pack `args`, which is impossible to do at runtime (since the loop is runtime). The only solution I have in mind is recurse: when finding opening bracket, read it, trim the format string, and recurse with the trimmed string and the rest of the variadic pack.

**Question:** is there a solution where it would be possible to expand the variadic pack at (pseudo) runtime?

Comment: What is `opening_bracket ` and `closing_bracket ` ? Why do you need that ? `fscanf` doesn't have anything like that AFAIK. A pseudo code on how you want it to work would go a long way in explaining than putting it in words.

Comment: @Arunmu, thanks, added

Comment: If you want to do it really efficiently, then you should use expression templates to get it done at compile time itself (the mapping). This can be done using `boost::proto`, though I admit it's not for the weak hearted :). The other solution that I know is only purely runtime since you are going to parse the brackets at runtime only. This would involve storing the args in a runtime container.

Comment: @Arunmu, I believe I will consider only {}, not {N}, since it will require magic to happen. Otherwise I could throw the function at the object, since I can't throw the object at the function.

Comment: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt already does something you want from what I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class=void,  std::size_t...Is >
auto indexer( std::index_sequence<Is...> ){
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto){
    return decltype(f)(f)( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto indexer(){
  return indexer(std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
template<std::size_t N>
void for_each( F&& f ) {
  indexer<N>()( [&](auto...Is){
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{0,(void(
      f(Is)
    ),0)...};
  });
}
```

`indexer` gives you unpacked indexes.

`for_each` calls `f` with a compile time `i` value for each `i` up to `N`.

That will let you iterate over integers at compile time.  To map integers at runtime to compile time:

```
template<std::size_t N, class F>
void pick( std::size_t I, F&& f ){
  for_each<N>( [&](auto i){
    if (I==i) f(i);
  } );
}
```

This invokes `f` with a compile time version of `I` so long as it is less than `N`.

```
template<class...Args>
void read( std::string pattern, Args&...args ){
  auto tied=std::tie(args...);
  for (i = 0; i < length; i = format.find(i, opening_bracket))  
    pick<sizeof...(args)>( i, [&](auto i){
      std::cin>>std::get<i>(tied);
    } );
  }
}
```

Now there is an implicit chain of `if`s written by the above; you can replace with a jump table using a different technique.

Code not compiled; design is sound, but there are probably tyops.  Indexer can be found with google (I have written it on SO before).  I have written it as `for_each` directly, but I find the single pack version too useful.  Here I needed the separate pack version.  Pick just uses it.

Here is a jump table version of pick:

```
template<std::size_t N, class F>
void pick( std::size_t I, F&& f ){
  indexer<N>()([&](auto...Is){
    using table_f=void(*)(&f);
    const table_f table[]={
      +[](F&f){ f(decltype(Is){}); }...
    };
    table[I](f);
  });
}
```

Bounds checking not included.  This version does not require `for_each`, but some compilers break when asked o have a lambda with a parameter pack unexpanded inside a statement.

Comment: Thanks Template-Yoda.